# Display search results on new page

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a Wordpress page I'm working on with a search function that pulls from a database hosted on Amazon AWS.

When searching, I can pull the data just fine, but the results display below the search bar.
I'd like the results to display on its own separate page.

I've tried several suggestions using previously asked questions, though nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Database */
?>

<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

if( strlen($query_string) > 0 ) {
  foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
  } // foreach
} //if

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>


<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php
$db_hostname = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db_username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db_database = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con){
  die('404 Could not connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);

  global $sf_options;
    $sidebar_config = $sf_options['archive_sidebar_config'];
    $left_sidebar   = $sf_options['archive_sidebar_left'];
    $right_sidebar  = $sf_options['archive_sidebar_right'];
    $blog_type      = $sf_options['archive_display_type'];

    if ( $blog_type == "masonry" || $blog_type == "masonry-fw" ) {
      global $sf_include_imagesLoaded;
      $sf_include_imagesLoaded = true;
    }
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <center>
    <form role="" method="get" >
      <p style="color: #fff;">Search products and services for your business. We make it easier<br />to manage your business operations and make informed purchasing decisions.</p>
      <input type="text" name="term" placeholder="Start typing to find a product or business"/>
      <span><input type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-default" /></span>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>

<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

  $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wpfr_listing WHERE Description LIKE '%".$term."%'";
  $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){

    echo '<br /> Company: ' .$row['title'];
    echo '<br /> Certs: '.$row['certs'];
    echo '<br /> Certifier: '.$row['certifier'];
    echo '<br /> Address: '.$row['address'];
    echo '<br /> Country: '.$row['country'];
    echo '<br /> State: '.$row['state'];
    echo '<br /> City: '.$row['city'];
  }

}
?>
```

Any help provided is much appreciated.

Comment: oh boy this code is so vulnerable. To help you with ur question: try adding `if (empty($_REQUEST['term']))` before your form, then change the `if` below the form to `else`

Comment: What makes this code vulnerable? It was written by a developer we no longer use.

Comment: mysql_ commands are deprecated (changed to mysqli_) and having the credentials to connect to db in the same file is not a good practice. Overall, it is better switch to PDO than using mysqli_ . http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write on this page

```
<?php if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) { 
header("location: page_url?term=".$_REQUEST['term']);
}
?>
```

And on serach result page

```
   <?php
 $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wpfr_listing WHERE Description LIKE '%".$term."%'";
     $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
    echo '<br /> Company: ' .$row['title']; 
    echo '<br /> Certs: '.$row['certs']; 
    echo '<br /> Certifier: '.$row['certifier'];
     echo '<br /> Address: '.$row['address'];
     echo '<br /> Country: '.$row['country']; echo '<br /> State: '.$row['state'];
     echo '<br /> City: '.$row['city'];
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want this done, via PHP, here you go.

1)create a new page. 
2)Have it handle a GET data of the query you have used here.
3) Print your search results as you have done in this page.

Now, in this page, you need to do a header redirect to that page The syntax for a header redirect is like this.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/?sql = <Your Query above>');
```

This should do it for you.  Hope this helps. Feel free to comment, if you need any further info.